# Circles and lines

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

I need to prove that $BO \perp CD$.

> Two circles $ω_1$ and $ω_2$ intersect at points $A$ and $B$. A line passing through point $B$ intersects ω1 at point $C$ and $ω_2$ at point $D$. Line $AC$ intersects circle $ω_2$ a second time at point $F$, and line $AD$ intersects circle a second time $ω_1$ at point $E$. Let $O$ be the center of the circumcircle around $\triangle AEF$. Prove that $OB\perp CD$.

[image]

I proved that $\angle CBE=\angle CAE= \angle FAD= \angle FBD$. So now I need to prove only that $\angle EBO= \angle FBO$. But I don't know how do this.

Comment: I think you should add some description to the figure.

Comment: you are right! i have did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost done!
[image]

You have already proved: $\angle CBE=\angle CAE=\angle DBF$.

Now prolong the line $BF$ till the second intersection with $\omega$ at $G$.
We have $\angle FGE=\angle FAE
\implies \angle FGE=\angle FBD
\implies (EG)\parallel (CD)\\
\implies \angle GEB=\angle CBE
\implies \angle GEB=\angle EGB$.

That means $\triangle EBG$ is isosceles and both $B$ and $O$ lie on the perpendicular bisector to $EG$.